# Is there a tool for generating crosstool files for installed compilers?

Tags: bazel

Bazel use `CROSSTOOL` files to figure out how to builds things. This can be used to (for example) switch between GCC and Clang by setting `--crosstool_top`. The problem is that it's far from trivial to construct those files.

Does anyone know of any tools that can inspect a Linux installation and generate the needed crosstool files for any "common" compiler(s) that happens to be installed? Something that would be able to find and support any installed versions of Clang and GCC would be enought, any other compilers (icc, etc.) would be fantastic.

(*Alternatively: are there any repo's with pre-constructed crosstool files for default installations of all the common compilers?*)

**Note**
I've already found `@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_configure.bzl` et al. but those seem to only generate  configs for the default system compiler and I'm specifically looking for support for the *non* default compiler(s).

Answer (score 0):

It's only a variation on `cc_configure`, but you can use environment variables to tweak the generation. Maybe using `CC` will be enough? If not, what else would you need (pull requests welcomed)?

There is no repo with premade crosstools yet, there will eventually be (maybe in the form of docker containers, we'll see) but currently there's not.

Comment: I'll have to try the `CC` override + `cc_configure`. Can that override be setup in the `.bazelrc` file? --- As to distribution of pre-made crosstools, If they aren't distributed with the compilers them selves, I'd rather prefer something that can just be trivially set up in the `WORKSPACE` file like other external deps. --- If you are thinking of using docker (or anything else) to install the *compiler* in that case, that is **not** something I'd be happy with.